# Effects of zero mean on covariance matrix

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance

Which effects on the covariance matrix provides the information that a random variable has a zero mean noise distribution? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Covariance is invariant under translations: $Cov(X-a,Y-b)=E[X-a-E[X-a],Y-b-E[Y-b]]=E[X-E[X],Y-E[Y]]=Cov(X,Y)$ for constants $a,b$.

Therefore, it is irrelevant what the mean is, as long as it exists.